# Linux Script - Extension retained

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a newbie to linux scripting and am having an issue with a script that I got from the web and am trying to modify.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
if (($# ==0))
then
    echo "Usage: flvto3gp [flv files] ..."
    exit
fi

while (($# !=0 ))
do 
    ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i $1 -f mjpeg   /home/zavids/rawvids/thumbs/$1.jpg
    shift
done
echo "Finished"
echo "\"fakap all those nonsense!\""
echo ""
```

So I'm grabbing a screenshot from a video and saving it as a jpeg. The problem is the extension of the video file is retained so finished file is video.flv.jpg (for example). How can I get rid of that video extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i $1 -f mjpeg   /home/zavids/rawvids/thumbs/$1.jpg
```

to this

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i $1 -f mjpeg /home/zavids/rawvids/thumbs/${1%.*}.jpg
```

That strips the extension from the input file before using it to create the name of the output file, using `bash` parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this :

```
${string%substring}
```

It deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

For your case :

```
${1%.flv}
```

This code will substitute .flv from the end of your first argument.

You can have a lot of details here too : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html